# Get Data from Stripe Webhook JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

I'm working with a Stripe Webhook and receiving the data successfully. I'm now trying to get individual elements out of the response but having trouble with this. Here's an example of the Webhook payload that is being sent/received:

```
{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "charge.captured",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": "2019-09-09",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "ch_00000000000000",
      "object": "charge",
      "amount": 100,
      "amount_refunded": 0,
      "application": null,
      "application_fee": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "balance_transaction": "txn_00000000000000",
      "billing_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": null,
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": null,
          "state": null
        },
        "email": null,
        "name": "Jenny Rosen",
        "phone": null
      },
      "captured": true,
      "created": 1572137813,
      "currency": "aud",
      "customer": null,
      "description": "My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
      "dispute": null,
      "failure_code": null,
      "failure_message": null,
      "fraud_details": {
      },
      "invoice": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "order": null,
      "outcome": null,
      "paid": true,
      "payment_intent": null,
      "payment_method": "card_00000000000000",
      "payment_method_details": {
        "card": {
          "brand": "visa",
          "checks": {
            "address_line1_check": null,
            "address_postal_code_check": null,
            "cvc_check": null
          },
          "country": "US",
          "exp_month": 8,
          "exp_year": 2020,
          "fingerprint": "OZhbqnP4UGjfz2sg",
          "funding": "credit",
          "installments": null,
          "last4": "4242",
          "network": "visa",
          "three_d_secure": null,
          "wallet": null
        },
        "type": "card"
      },
      "receipt_email": null,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_19tTXNGNdpzDd4Jh/ch_1FY03tGNdpzDd4Jhg9poqFWr/rcpt_G48KYZOYRKrGjAmC9bqOx6TkDAkQ19W",
      "refunded": false,
      "refunds": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1FY03tGNdpzDd4Jhg9poqFWr/refunds"
      },
      "review": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "source_transfer": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null
    }
  }
}
```

I'm doing the following in my PHP file:

```
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event= json_decode( $payload, TRUE );
$status = $event->data->object->status;
echo '$status: '.$status.'<br>';
```

which just returns `$status: <br>`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with trying to extract individual elements from the decoded JSON here such a the status and amount?

Comment: Try `$event= json_decode( $payload, FALSE );`

Comment: `json_decode( $payload, TRUE );`  - in this the `TRUE` will cause the data to be created as an (associative) array rather than an object (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). So `->` syntax won't work to get the properties. you could have debugged this by doing something like `var_dump($event);` to see the real variable you were getting from the decode operation.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does `$payload` contain the expected data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the `TRUE` parameter was the issue. Using:

```
$event= json_decode( $payload, FALSE );
```

made it work.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out with a little help from a dev on Stripe's irc!
You already posted your webhook data tree to know where the information is you need to pull but your example won't work because you are trying to pull data on a yet unknown condition. As per the sample code on Stripe for webhooks, the conditions are either;

payment_intent.succeeded OR payment_intent.failed

Your code needs to be inside these conditions, not before!

Here's a working and tested example which gives you a guide on how to approach this. Be aware that is according to my tree from the webhook, not yours but the only difference is the one line of code which is commented at the end.

```
<?php
// Payment success
if ($event->type == "payment_intent.succeeded") {
$intent = $event->data->object;
$order = $event->data->object->charges->data[0]->description; // this is my line of code
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Do your server stuff here for payment_intent.succeeded
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
printf("Succeeded: %s", $intent->id);
http_response_code(200);
?>
```

For you own specific purposes just replace the line I commented with your own;

```
<?php
$status = $event->data->object->status; // this is your line of code
?>
```

Now you're free to do whatever you want with that variable in either condition.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please choose it as the correct answer, if not, please state what the issue is.

Comment: The solution was just to use `$event= json_decode( $payload, FALSE );`